# Is there anyway for VS to implicilty generate update method for dataset based on a view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there anyway for Visual Studio to implicilty generate update method for dataset based on a view? 
Since my DataSet is based on views and not on table, I think that is the reason why Update method is not working/not-available.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for a [trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-EN/library/ms189799.aspx)?

Comment: No. Am not looking for a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be why using the update method on a DataSet object isn't working, since a view is a projection of the data in the database. I've never tried it, but a full ORM like the Entity Framework **might** do that, but I wouldn't count on it. You'll probably need to write your updates by hand.